# Can I use a shared library compiled by C from C++ using dlopen

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

firstly I tried to create simple  shared library in C and called the library using dlopen and worked fine. Then I have a requirement that I can have a cpp file to call the c compiled shared library.

in the simple program calling was fine. Does this mean that we can call c created library from c++ in larger program ???

In soe document of using dlopen in C++, it was mentioned to use extern as I suppose that shared library is written in C++ thus it is to be transformed to C Like . Aand if it is already in c. we are not in need of using extern and directly use from c++.

Am I correct??

Comment: `dlopen` is part of the Posix standard, so if your platform supports Posix, then you can use `dlopen`.

Answer (score 0):

On all major operating systems the calling conventions for functions are the same for C and C++ compilations. The major difference C++ adds is, that class member functions have an additional, implicit parameter (the `this` pointer) and get their name mangled in order to reflect the type signature, so that a single function name can be overloaded. Other than that calling a function works the same for C and C++.

When you use `dlopen` and later `dlsym` the only thing of concern is the naming of the symbol. However since you're intending to access a C library vom C++ name mangling is not an issue; you can use just the symbol identifiers as you originally wrote them.

Comment: on what platform/environment is dlopen? I don't have it in VC2008.

Comment: dlopen is normally found on *nix-systems (Linux, the *BSDs, MacOS X). The Windows equivalent would be `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`

Comment: The "as you originally write them" is misleading: you must tell C++ that the interface uses C semantics to avoid having the C++ compiler mangle the names.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: No you don't have to. Why? Because OP is asking to call functions compiled with a C compiler (hence no name mangling) and the symbol is looked up using a string, i.e. `GetProcAddress("foo")` or `dlsym("foo")` – the arguments are regular string literals, which a compiler of course must not transform. Name mangling only applies to entries in the import symbol table, but when using `GetProcAddress` or `dlsym` no import symbol table entries are generated at all.